# Solution of the wave equation $\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2} = c^2\Delta U$?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

how to show that 
$$U(X,t) = r^{−1}\ g(ct − r)\ ,$$

where $r = |X|$, and $X = (x,y,z)$, is a solution of the wave equation in dimension 3, i.e., $U$ satisfies

$$ \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2} = c^2\bigg(\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial z^2} \bigg)\ .$$

Comment: Hi, I edited the question to make it more readable. Please check if I mistakenly change the meaning of your question.

Comment: by substitution

Comment: how to substitute? could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

The laplician in spherical coordinates of a function $f(t,r)$ is:

$$
\frac 1{r^2}\partial_r(r^2\partial_rf) = 
$$
For such a function, the wave equation is
$$ \frac {r}{c^2} \partial_{tt}^2 f = \frac 1{r}\partial_r(r^2\partial_rf)
=2r\partial_rf + r\partial^2_{rr} f = \partial^2_{rr} (rf)
$$
via the Leibnitz formula.

So $rf$ is a solution of the $1D$ wave equation, so takes the form
$$
f(t,r) = F(ct - r) + G(ct + r)
$$

Answer (score 0):

A direct proof in attachment :

[image]